How to paint a gradient color background of a TDBGrid cell in delphi
My goal is to draw a Delphi TDBgrid cell to have a gradient color from right to left, like the image below:

I used the GradientFillCanvas procedure from the Vcl.GraphUtil unit.
Here is my custom OnDrawColumnCell event handler:
procedure TMainForm.MyDBGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  if DM1.ABST_DV.RecNo mod 2=1 then
  begin
    GradientFillCanvas(MyDBGrid.Canvas, 
      clWhite,clGradientInactiveCaption,Rect, `gdHorizontal);

    MyDBGrid.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
  end else
  begin
    GradientFillCanvas(MyDBGrid.Canvas, 
      clWhite,clGradientInactiveCaption, Rect, gdHorizontal);
    MyDBGrid.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
  end;
end;

The problem is, with this code in the OnDrawColumnCell event, the contents of the TDBGrid do not appear.
Here is my new code:
procedure TMainForm.MyDBGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState); 
begin
  GradientFillCanvas(MyDBGrid.Canvas, 
    clWhite,clGradientInactiveCaption,Rect, `gdHorizontal);
  MyDBGrid.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
  MyDBGrid.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,Column.Field.DisplayText); 
end;

but when i compile, an error occurs and the message below is shown.

[DCC Erreur] uMain.pas(1349): E2250 Aucune version surchargée de 'TextRect' ne peut être appelée avec ces arguments


The content does not appear because you are not drawing it.  You need to draw the cell's text after drawing its background.  You can use the MyDBGrid.Canvas.TextRect() method for that purpose.
TDBGrid does have a DefaultDrawDataCell() method, which draws a cell and its text, and which can be customized using the OnDrawColumnCell event, but it only supports drawing solid backgrounds, so it will draw over your custom background.  You could try using a transparent Brush to work around that, though.

with the code below (using MyDBGrid.Canvas.TextRect()), an error occure when compiling in the OnDrawDataCell event. Here is the code.

when inserting the code below in the OnDrawDataCell() Event of MyGrid and compile, the IDE send this message.

with the code below (using MyDBGrid.Canvas.TextRect()), an error occure when compiling in the OnDrawDataCell event. Here is the code.
f:=MyTable.field[0].Designation;
s:=MyTable.Designation.AsString;
if field.Name='Description' then MyDBGrid.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,s)

@bedia That information should be added as an edit to your question, and please include the actual error message. And then delete those comments.

thanks for all.
i used the TextOut metod of TCanvas object. Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextOut.
and the code was MyDBGrid.Canvas.TextOut(Rect,Column.Field.DisplayText);
and thanks fr all again.
